# Need material I can step on to remove dog hair from shoes (electrostatic?)

Tags: cleaning, adhesive

Want material I can step on that will remove dog hair via static electricity or mild stickiness.

Comment: Hi Erik, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. A search using "cleaner," "step-on," and "shoe" produced hundreds of sources for your request. Please visit the Help Center (the ? icon in the upper-right corner of the menu bar) to find out what kinds of questions are on-topic here. https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Rub a balloon? That might work, or use regular scotch tape

Comment: Have you tried *welcome mats*? They are bristly mats often placed just outside the front door for people to clean the soles of their shoes. They don't rely on static electricity or stickiness, so aren't a good fit for your question. But they are pretty cheap and readily available.

Answer (score 1):

**How to make a shoe depilatory** (hair remover).

Wrap adhesive tape around your hand a few times, sticky-side out.  You can use masking tape, rug tape, duct tape, gaffer's tape, Gorilla tape, packing tape, etc.

Make 4 of these wads of tape.

Put a couple of these wads of tape beside each other on the floor in-line for one shoe. Put another couple a few inches away parallel to the first two for the other shoe.

Step on them to transfer the unwanted hair from the bottom of your shoes to the tape. This should work one or two times. Flip the flat wads over and you're good for a couple of more depilatory applications before you discard them.

Tread and repeat as necessary.

**Disclaimer**. This is a hack for temporary mis-use. Clean rooms, and surgical areas cover your shoes before entry. You might try using disposable shoe booties, too. Stick pads are also provided also use stick mats for removing dust and dirt but to be successful the mats are long length and are followed by a shallow flowing water wash. Also be warned that to be effective, stick mats are to be used repeatedly. Research has shown that some particles remain after seven attempts at removal.

Comment: Stan since English is a funky language, I had to read your 2nd paragraph twice. That first word ("wind") also describes a breeze, as in the song "All the colors of the wind". I didn't know what "wind masking" was.  It sounded like a device for wind-powered turbines. That's why I edited this! I gave it an upvote too.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Fixed.